# React js lodash set the state changes but the state is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I should change the value of the element to a certain depth, I am using lodash, but I am having problems.

I make the copy of the object, and applying the lodash set on the copy I modify the original so you are.

I try to change the state, but it doesn't update.

You can help me out.

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-q4i7y)

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import ReactJson from "react-json-view";
import lodash from "lodash";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    "& > *": {
      margin: theme.spacing(1),
      width: 200
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    name: "James",
    surname: "bond",
    card: {
      id: 7,
      group: "J"
    },
    scope: [{ scope: "user", actions: ["create", "delete"] }]
  });

  const handleChangeField = field => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    let newState = Object.assign(state, {});
    console.log(state, field, value);
    lodash.set(newState, field, value);
    setState(newState);
  };

  console.log("Change", state);

  return (
    <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <ReactJson
        src={state}
        theme={"solarized"}
        enableClipboard={false}
        displayObjectSize={false}
      />

      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Name"
        onChange={handleChangeField("name")}
      />
      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Group"
        onChange={handleChangeField("card.group")}
      />
      <TextField
        id="standard-basic"
        label="Action[0]"
        onChange={handleChangeField("scope[0].actions[0]")}
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: `Object.assign` is a shallow copy. Make a deep copy. Use lodash clonedeep

Comment: Or use lodash/fp `_.set()` which doesn't mutate the original object.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Because lodash.set mutates the value. You can use lodash/fp.

With lodash/fp:

```js
import set from 'lodash/fp/set';

const handleChangeField = field => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    setState(set(field, value, state););
};
```

this `set` returns a new object.